# Return array from function in c++ through pointer, but how does the program know the array size?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

For example, I have a function as below.

```
int* function(int a)
{
    int b = 2;
    int *c = new int[b];
    return c;
}
```

My main function calls it like this:

```
int main()
{
    int *array = function(123);
    return 0;
}
```

However, I have no idea the array length of `array` because I passed a pointer. Apparently, `sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)` does not work for pointer array. Therefore, I cannot display or use the array because I don't know the size of it. Is there anyway to let the function return both the size (or calculate it) and the array? Thanks!

Please recommend the remedy before providing alternative solutions such as using a vector.

Comment: Save yourself the trouble and use `std::vector`.

Comment: what is your vaiable "a" for? does it have any sense or is it just dummy parameter?

Comment: @return 0 can you elaborate? otherwise it is not clear what you asked for

Comment: @privatedatapublicchannel2: That's obvioulsy simply noise in the example.

Comment: Using a vector _is_ the remedy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the specific problem, you would pass a pointer or a reference to an integer as well to the function, that would be updated by the function to store the size of the array. It's used often in library design.

```
int* function(int a, int* size)
{
    int b = 2;
    *size = b;
    int *c = new int[b];
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    int sizeofarray;
    int *array = function(123, &sizeofarray);
    return 0;
}
```

*P.S. Deduplicator is right about using standard containers :-)

Answer (score 3):

Your question makes perfect sense because the C++ runtime must know how big the array that was allocated is.

However while it's true that the runtime given a pointer can find the size of the memory block allocated with `new[]` and the number of elements of the allocated array (at least if destruction requires code) there is no portable way to get this information with C++ code.

The standard solution is to just return an `std::vector` instance instead that is slightly more that a pointer and a size (a very common implementation is just a pointer, a size for the used part and a size for the available extra memory for new elements that wouldn't require a reallocation).

Comment: The size of the memory-block is only loosely related to the number of elements and their type it stores anyway.

Comment: @Deduplicator: That is true for `malloc`, but for a C++ array allocated with `new[]` the runtime must know the number of elements too (to be able to call destructors when `delete[]` is called).

Comment: Only if there is a non-trivial destructor. Basic types may not apply. Even then, element count is extra bookkeeping data, still only loosely related to the memory block size.

Comment: @Deduplicator: the point is that indeed the question makes perfect sense because the C++ runtime knows how to get back array description from the pointer, but (unfortunately) for a C++ program there is no portable way to get it.

Comment: The C++ runtime does not need to (and often, especially in this situation cannot) recover the allocated type or the number of elements allocated. It has to trust you to remember right, and use the pointer appropriately. Even if you guaranteed that `new int[#]` was used, it still might be unable to get the element count.

Answer (score 2):

You are in C++, use a class, like `std::tuple`. Anyway, raw pointers are frowned upon, better use a standard container like `std::vector` if possible.

If you really want to do neither, you must pass the length some other way, by using a pointer or a reference for example. You might instead make use a sentinel value or make the length contractual though.

As some seem to think the C++ runtime must have a secret marker providing the type and element count originally asked for, just to be clear: Most common implementations save neither for most cases, and only the element count for allocations using `new[]` of a type having non-trivial destructor or a custom `new[]` `delete[]`-pair demanding the element count.

Answer (score 1):

A trivial solution could be

```
struct array
{
    int *data;
    int  size;
};

array function(int a)
{
    int b = 3;
    int *c = new int[b];
    array arr = { c, b };
    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    array arr = function(123);
    std::cout << arr.size;
    return 0;
}
```